# Is Any is the same as Forall a.a?

Tags: python, types

Python has the `Any` type which is 'is-consistent' with any type. Isn't it possible to express `Any` using the type represented in Haskell as `forall a.a` instead of adding a new type?

Comment: Please clarify, what is `Forall a.a`?

Comment: `Forall a.a ` - universal type on the left side of which there are type variables. For example, Haskell's `id` is of type `Forall a. a->a`

Comment: It'd help if you'd stick to one language/notation…

Comment: `forall a. a` is the uninhabited type in Haskell. `forall a. a -> a` is a *different* type, whose *only* value is `id`.

Comment: I apologize, but it seemed to me that the id of their Haskell is a very suitable and well-known example.

In Python it would look like this
`T = typing.TypeVar('T')`

`def id(x: T) -> T:`
    `return x`
As far as I know, in the literature, regardless of the language, the type of such a function would be written as `∀a. a -> a`

Comment: Even if they were the same, you'd still have to add `forall a. a` to Python, because it's not already there.

Comment: `forall a.a` is certainly not a "universal" type, which would be a *union* of all types. It's more like the *intersection* of all types.

Comment: I've tried editing the question in a way that clarifies the intent without making it basically answer itself. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are different.

`forall a. a` is an uninhabited type. (A universal type would be a *union* of all other types; this is more like an *intersection* of all other types.) The only thing you can assign to a variable with that type is bottom:

```hs
-- With the ExplicitForAll option set in GHC
x, y :: forall a.a
x = undefined  -- OK
y = 'c' -- Not OK
```

As such, it's the type most commonly used to indicate that a function never returns, either because it *diverges* (goes into an infinite loop)

```hs
> :t let f = f in f
let f = f in f :: t  -- forall t. t
```

or because it raises an exception.

```hs
> :t error
error :: [Char] -> t  -- forall t. [Char] -> t
```

---

`Any` is a pseudotype that is *consistent* with all other types, without being a sub- or supertype of any other type.

```
x: Any = 1  # OK
y: Any = 'c' # OK
```

Neither `1` nor `'c'` is an *instance* of `Any`, but the assignments are allowed according to the definition of consistency.

In some sense, Python has *two* equivalents of `forall a. a`, at least for type-checking, `typing.NoReturn` and `typing.Never`. The latter was introduce in Python 3.11 as a clearer alternative to the former, but they are otherwise equivalent. (`NoReturn` was meant exclusively as a return-type annotation, while `Never` is explicitly intended to represent an empty type, which has uses other than as the return type of a non-returning function. `NoReturn` seems to be unofficially deprecated.)

---

Consistency is the extension of subtyping to a "universe" in which `Any` has been added as a special type. As stated in [PEP 483](https://peps.python.org/pep-0483/) (in the [Summary of gradual typing](https://peps.python.org/pep-0483/#summary-of-gradual-typing)),

> - A type `t1` is consistent with a type `t2` if `t1` is a subtype of `t2`. (But not the other way around.)
> - `Any` is consistent with every type. (But `Any` is not a subtype of every type.)
> - Every type is consistent with `Any`. (But every type is not a subtype of `Any`.)